# how pass a property from initialize event to an Ajax.Request object inside the same class - Prototype

Tags: prototypejs

On the code below, i'm trying to use this.loadingImage1 from initialize event in another method's ajax.request object but it just displays 'undefined'.

```
var ActivityJS = Class.create({
initialize : function(options)
{
    this.options = {
        school          : options.school,
        htaccessPage    : options.htaccessPage
    };
    this.loadingImage1 = (options.pageId == ''?"img1":"img2");
},  deleteTask: function(taskId)
{
    var params =    "id="+taskId;       

    var ajax = new Ajax.Request(this.widgetUrl,{
        method: 'POST',
        parameters: params,
        evalJS: true,
        onLoading: function()
        {
            $(dvId).innerHTML = "<img src='"+this.loadingImage1+"' />";
        },
        onComplete: function(response)
        {
            $(dvId).update(response.responseText);
            setTimeout(function() {
                Lightview.hide();
                window.location.reload();
            }, 2000);  
        }
    });
}
});
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What if you use `bind()` (http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/bind) on `onLoading`

```
onLoading: function() {...}.bind(this),
```